# Given a line, find a point co-ordinate (or co-ordinates) at an angle and in a given distance

Tags: geometry

[image: Illustrated Image]

Given

1. 2-d coordinates of $a$ and $b$
2. Distance $d$ at which we need a point ($x$ and/or $y$)
3. Angle $r$

Can we find co-ordinates of x, y?.
If so, please share the formula or method to find it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

$$A = B - \frac{|AB| |BC|} {\rm{vector}\ BC}  \cos \theta$$

Where $\rm{vector}(AB) = B - A$ and $\rm{vector}(BC) = C-B$.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by dividing by a vector. Did you mean to divide by the length (in which case it would cancel out with the same length in the numerator)? I've written out the correct steps in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Take the vectors $\vec {ap}=(x_1-a_x, \; y_1-a_y)$ and $\vec {ab}=(b_x-a_x, \; b_y-a_y)$, then make the system:

$|\vec {ap}| = d$  and

$\vec {ap} / |$\vec {ap}| ; \cdot ; \vec {ap} / |$\vec {ap}|= cos (r)$

you will get a quadratic for $x_1,y_1$ whose two solutions will give you the two points.