# Determine end coordinates of a segment

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to determine the coordinates of point P in a 2D Space, given the coordinates A and B, a 90 degree angle between BA and BP and known length of BP. How do I approach this?

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1HE3.jpg)

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856928/given-a-line-find-a-point-co-ordinate-or-co-ordinates-at-an-angle-and-in-a-gi/3856939#3856939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of approaching this.

One way: You can find the line through $AB$, what is its the relationship to the line $BP$? When you figure this out you can use the fact that you know the length $BP$ to figure out the desired coordinates.

A second way: You can find a point $C$ along $AB$ such that $CB$ has the same length as $BP$ and then rotate it $\frac{\pi}{2}$ degrees anticlockwise via the rotation matrix.

Hope that helps, if you have any issues let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing points A (a1,a2) and B(b1,b2) you can calculate the slope of line AB, m1= (b2- a2)/(b1- a1) (assuming that AB is not vertical).  BP is perpendicular to AB so has slope m2= (a1- b1)/(b2- a2) (assuming AB is not horizontal).

So the line BP is given by y= m2(x-b1)+ b2. We can write P as (xp, m2(xp- b1)+ b2) Taking the given length of BP to be "L", $\sqrt{(xp- a2)^2+ (m2(xp- b1))^2}= L$.

Solve that equation for xp.

(If AB is vertical then BP is horizontal.  P= (b1+ L, b2).  If AB is horizontal then BP is vertical.  P= (b1, b2+ L).)

I just notice that I am assuming one direction for the perpendicular.  The other way will change signs.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture of the problem that you presented, those points look to be A at $(2,3)$ and B at $(8,7)$. You didn't provide the lengths of AB or BP, but I think I can work from that...

1. To find the difference AB, I will have to draw a right triangle making AB the hypotenuse by dropping a point C at $(8, 3)$. From this, I know that AC has a distance of 6 and BC 4. So the distance of AB must be $\overline{AB}=\sqrt{4^2+6^2}$. (This isn't a rational number, so I'll return to this later.
2. Since $\overline{AB}$ has two defined points, I can see that the slope of the line is defined by $\frac{7-3}{8-2}=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$. Taking this, I can put this formula into slope-intercept form to get the equation of the line.
   $$
   y-7=\frac{2(x-8)}{3}
   $$
   $$
   y-7=\frac{2x-16}{3}
   $$
   $$
   y=\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{21-16}{3}
   $$
   $$
   y=\frac{2x+5}{3}
   $$

Knowing this, and that a perpendicular slope is equal to $\frac{-1}{m}$, I know that the slope of $\overline{BP}$ is $\frac{-3}{2}$

3. Now I simply do slope-intercept form with one point to find the equation of the line. Doing this returns $y=\frac{-3x}{2}+19$
4. I know that the distance between B and P is some value $d$ (which isn't provided in the image). Because of this and knowing that the hypotenuse of the whole triangle is $\sqrt{52}$, I know that $\sin(\theta)=\frac{d}{\sqrt52}$ or $\arcsin(\frac{d}{\sqrt{52}})=\theta$
5. Now knowing $\theta$, we can do $180-(90+\theta)=\beta$ (where $\beta$ is the angle formed by BPA). Knowing $\beta$, we know that $\sin(\beta)=\frac{b_{2}}{d}$ which means that to find $b_{2}$ (the amount to subtract from 7 to get the y coördinate of P), $b_{2}=d\sin(\beta)$
6. Having the y-coördinate of P, to find the X, simply plug the y into the perpendicular equation from step 3:

$$
7-(-d\sin(\beta))=\frac{-3x}{2}+19
$$
$$
7+d\sin(\beta)=\frac{-3x}{2}+19
$$
$$
\frac{-2(d\sin(\beta)-12)}{3}=x
$$

*QED* P rests at point $(\frac{-2(d\sin(\beta)-12)}{3}, d\sin(\beta)$ such that $\beta=90º-\arcsin(\frac{d}{\sqrt{52}})$